# Not able to override previously build project with the user having developer roles on kie-wb-7.5.0.(drools)

Tags: drools, drools-planner, drools-kie-server, redhat-brms, drools-kie-workbench

I am not able to override the previously build project when I build&deploy it with the user having developer roles on  kie-wb-7.5.0.Final-eap7. I have given all the permissions to the developer.

how we can give the developer, the permissions to override the project build?

permissions to the developer:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask